# Spring sleuth and spring integration generating the same traceId for all outbound API requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, resttemplate, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm building a springboot app which use spring integration and spring sleuth as well. The app reads from a csv file and for each record in the csv file a call is made to an API using spring resttemplate. Each time a file is read, all corresponding calls to the API are having the same X-B3-TraceId. They do have a different spanId.

I would like to have different X-B3-TraceId for each call to the API. I believe the spring integration is setting a traceId for each file read operation and using the same throughout during each call to the API.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow bridgeFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(ABC_SERVICE_QUEUE_CHANNEL)
            .bridge(e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(period).maxMessagesPerPoll(MAX_MSG_PER_POLL)))
            .handle(someService, "someMethod")
            .route(router())               
            .get();
}
```

"someMethod" has the call to the API using resttemplate as,

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(someUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

I tried manually setting the X-B3-TraceId headers but that seem to be getting overridden

Comment: which version of Sleuth are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to override some header with your own value, you should use something like this in your `IntegrationFlow`:

```
.enrichHeaders(s -> s.header("X-B3-TraceId", "some_value", true))
```

The last argument is important here to be set to `true`.
See its JavaDocs:

```
@param overwrite true to overwrite an existing header.
```

On the other hand it is not clear from your code snippet how that `X-B3-TraceId` header appears in the message at all. Who sets it for us? And where is your file reader and splitter for records in it?